# Sending Sms using a QT Desktop application without using a website

Tags: c++, qt, sms

Is there a way to send an SMS from a QT Desktop application without using a website?

Comment: Not a built-in way, no.

Comment: even a method that is not built in would be of great help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, connect a GSM modem to your PC and send it via the modem. You need some way to get your message into the SMS network, and wirelessly is the logical way.